# Run a job via the rundeck API with parameters in postman

Tags: api, postman, rundeck

I am trying around with the Rundeck API. I was able to get a simple Job running. But now I am trying to run a job, that has a job option. The job option for this job is an IP, so Rundeck starts the Job only on this machine.
When I use the API, I don't know how to set the parameter. I am using the tool Postman, where I only receive the message "Job options were not valid: Option 'IP' is required".

I looked it up on the [rundeck documentation](https://docs.rundeck.com/docs/api/rundeck-api.html#running-a-job) and I found [this](https://documenter.getpostman.com/view/95797/rundeck/7TNfX9k?version=latest#729a5230-a7a0-062f-e1b0-7a04a3cae6bf) for postman

In the rundeck documentation is this example:

> argString: argument string to pass to the job, of the form: `-opt value -opt2 value ....`

How can I use it for my IP?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using this [Rundeck Job Definition](https://docs.rundeck.com/docs/manual/creating-jobs.html#importing-job-definitions):

```yaml
- defaultTab: nodes
  description: ''
  executionEnabled: true
  id: 9f04657a-eaab-4e79-a5f3-00d3053f6cb0
  loglevel: INFO
  name: HelloWorld
  nodeFilterEditable: false
  options:
  - name: opt1
  plugins:
    ExecutionLifecycle: null
  scheduleEnabled: true
  sequence:
    commands:
    - exec: echo "hello ${option.opt1}"
    keepgoing: false
    strategy: node-first
  uuid: 9f04657a-eaab-4e79-a5f3-00d3053f6cb0
```

And based on [this](https://kcaps.medium.com/calling-rundeck-api-job-with-opt-with-postman-8dbf17c17da7), you can do it by putting the options in JSON format (json body) on Postman:

```json
{
    "options": {
        "opt1":"world"
    }
}
```

This is the code snipped in cURL format:

```sh
curl --location --request POST 'pop-os:4440/api/38/job/9f04657a-eaab-4e79-a5f3-00d3053f6cb0/run' \
--header 'X-Rundeck-Auth-Token: GuaoD6PtH5BhobhE3bAPo4mGyfByjNya' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--header 'Cookie: JSESSIONID=node01tz8yvp4gjkly8kpj18h8u5x42.node0' \
--data-raw '{
    "options": {
        "opt1":"world"
    }
}'
```

Check how [looks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nsn5n.jpg) on Postman.